# preg_match_all with spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

have some headers like:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 400 Not Found
```

so, I need to get 2 parts:

```
[200] => [OK]
[400] => [Not Found]
```

I need a way to use `preg_match_all` and get those values, but need to preserve the spaces at `Not Found`

have this code:

```
preg_match_all( '/([0-9]{3}) ([A-Za-z0-9+]*)/', $headers, $matches );
```

Works with 1-3 example headers.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have an array of those status codes if you want it.

Comment: If each of these is its own line/input, you could just use explode() with a limit:  
`list($http, $status, $msg) = explode(' ', $line, 3);`

Comment: No need for `preg_match_all`. With this structure, `explode` should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the single line and for the text in general

```
$str = "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 400 Not Found";

// for the values in the string, one on each line
preg_match_all('#(\d{3})\s+([\w\s]+)$#m', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);  // captures a new line symbol if exists

// for single value in the string
$str = "HTTP/1.1 400 Not Found";
preg_match('#(\d{3})\s+([\w\s]+)$#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

So, do you have each header on a new line or not?

Comment: what are those "#" chars? shouldn't that be forward slash?

Comment: @jperovic  It can be anything, just a matter of habit.

Comment: @jperovic Some languages requires slashes, but [delimiters in PHP/PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)  _"can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character."_

Answer (score 3):

You can give your regex matches a name with `(?P<name>)`, making your code more readable. also you can go with a much easier regex:

```
preg_match('#HTTP/1\.\d (?P<code>\d{3}) (?P<text>.*)#', $str, $matches);
echo $matches['code']; // 2100", same as $matches[1]
echo $matches['text']; // "Continue", same as $matches[2]

preg_match_all('#HTTP/1\.\d (?P<code>\d{3}) (?P<text>.*)#', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo $matches[0]['code']; // 100
echo $matches[0]['text']; // Continue
echo $matches[3]['code']; // 404
echo $matches[3]['text']; // Not Found
```

or even more simple, without regex using `explode()`:

```
list(,$code,$text) = explode(" ", $str, 3); // works only on a single status line
echo $code; // 100
echo $text; // Continue
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using almost good regexp but you're missing `[ ]` (space) from the character group definition, it should be: `/([0-9]{3}) ([A-Za-z0-9 +]*)/`.

Or rather use

- `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z]`
- `\d` instead of `[0-9]` and
- `\s` instead of `[ ]`

So your patter would look like:

```
/(\d{3}) ([\w\d\s+]*)/
```

And make sure it won't match something it shouldn't

```
/HTTP\/1\.\d (\d{3}) ([\w\d\s+]+)/
```

So whole code would look like:

```
preg_match_all( '/HTTP\/1\.\d (\d{3}) ([\w\d\s+]+)/', $headers, $matches );
```

[Here's an explanation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) for escape sequences.